# Documents not expiring using TTL in mongodb 3.0 (.Net driver 2.0)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have the following code. The EnsureIndexes is called by the constructor to make sure that a TTL index has been created on the _expireAt field. Then when a document is inserted by calling the AddOrUpdateItem method, it adds a future date to the _expireAt field. However, that date passes and the document never expires. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void EnsureIndexes()
    {
        if (!_indexChecked)
        {
            // TTL index
            var tsk = 
                MongoCollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<BsonDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending("_expireAt"),
                        new CreateIndexOptions() { ExpireAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0) });

            tsk.Wait();

            _indexChecked = true;
        }
    }
public void AddOrUpdateItem(string key, TValue value, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var json = value.ToJson();
        dynamic jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        jObject._expireAt = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(timeout);
        json = jObject.ToString();

        var replacementDocument = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);
        var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", key);
        var options = new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true};
        var tsk = MongoCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, replacementDocument, options);

        try
        {
            tsk.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            // TODO: Log

            throw;
        }
    }
```

The following is returned with the command to getIndices on the Mongo collection.

```
> db.Users.getIndices()
```

[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "*id*",
                "ns" : "AuditDemo.Users"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_expireAt" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_expireAt_1",
                "ns" : "AuditDemo.Users",
                "expireAfterSeconds" : 0
        }
]
>

In my AddOrUpdateItem method I first serialize a generic type to json in order to be able to add a dynamic element for the expireAt. Then I use the BsonSerializer to deserialize this modified json into a BsonDocument. At this point, does the BsonDocument translate the datetime json string to a BSon date type in order for the TTL index to work?

Result from the findOne command

```
> db.Users.findOne({"_expireAt":{$exists: true}})
```

{
        "_id" : "0",
        "UserGuid" : {
                "Value" : "054f6141-e655-41dd-a9d5-39382d3360ab"
        },
        "UserName" : null,
        "FirstName" : {
                "Value" : "JORDAN"
        },
        "LastName" : {
                "Value" : "ACEVEDO"
        },
        "Email" : {
                "Value" : "JORDAN.ACEVEDO@fake.com"
        },
        "__typ" : "AuditDemo.ConsoleApplication.Models.Wss.UserInfo, ConsoleTest
App, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
        "_expireAt" : "2015-05-31T10:23:15.8979321Z"
}
>

Comment: Please add the output of `db.YourCollection.getIndices()` to your question using the edit button.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: I updated the original post with the result from the call to getIndices. The index does indeed exist. But I suspect what might be going on here is in the deserialization of a json document to bson, the BsonSerializer might not be converting the json date string to a Bson date data type. If that is the case, then how do you store json documents with an expiration.

Comment: Um, let's check. Please add the output of `db.Users.findOne({"_expireAt":{$exists: true}})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out how to correct this date issue. The date time string that I got from JSON.Net, was not getting stored a BSON date object. So I had to call the BsonDateTime.create() method on the deserialized BsonDocument property and force it to be a BSON date. When it gets stored in the correct data type, the TTL index works as expected.

```
        DateTime expiresDate = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc).Add(timeout);
        var replacementDocument = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);
        replacementDocument["_expireAt"] = BsonDateTime.Create(expiresDate);
        var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", key);
        var options = new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true};
        var tsk = MongoCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, replacementDocument, options);
```